# OpenCV Native Library path issue

Tags: java, opencv

Hello I'm creating a program and I'm using opencv to take a picture from the camera, so far so good. I am able to take the picture and show it in screen. The issue comes when my partners try to use the program from their eclipse IDE it doesn't work because the native library path is the one of my computer I believe.

Someone know how to solve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Replace path with his one? Or make paths relative & keep opencv in the project folder by 3dparty dir?

Comment: I think the one I need is the relative path but I have tried and it doesn't work then. I have added the .dll file to the lib file and try that but doesn't work.

Comment: Solved, I added the dll file to the lib folder and added this System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); instead of System.loadLibrary(".//lib");